# Client-side function doesn't exist in server-component in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In Next.js 14 App Router, I try to run a function in a server-side component like this:

```
import { getData } from "@/api/data/Data.service";
import { toast } from "@/components/toaster";

export default async function Page() {
  let data = {};
  try {
    data = await getData();
    toast({ type: "success", message: "Data is fetched!" });
  } catch (error) {
    toast({ type: "error", message: "Failed fetching data!" });
  }

  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  );
}
```

The function is declared in a client-side file and renders a client-side component before returning a string.

```
"use client";

import { CustomAlert } from "@/components/alert";
import * as React from "react";
import hotToast, { Toaster as HotToaster } from "react-hot-toast";

export const Toaster = HotToaster;

interface ToastProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  visible: boolean;
}

export function Toast({ visible, className, ...props }: ToastProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`tw-w-full tw-max-w-lg tw-pt-[4.5rem] tablet:tw-pt-[5.5rem] laptop:tw-pt-[6.5rem]
        ${visible && "tw-animate-in tw-slide-in-from-bottom-5"}
        ${className}
      `}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

interface ToastOptions {
  title?: string;
  message: string;
  type?: "error" | "success" | "warning" | "info";
}

export function toast(options: ToastOptions) {
  const { title, message, type = "info" } = options;

  setTimeout(() => hotToast.remove(), 5000);

  return hotToast.custom(
    ({ visible }) => (
      <Toast visible={visible}>
        <CustomAlert skin={type} title={title}>
          {message}
        </CustomAlert>
      </Toast>
    ),
    {}
  );
}
```

When trying to run the function, I receive an error telling me that the function doesn't exist (`(0 , _components_toaster__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.toast) is not a function`). The same function runs normally when used in a client-side component.

Comment: You are not importing your function anywhere in your server component. However even if you import the function it aint gonna to work.

Comment: Sorry, the import was only missing here. But can this toaster only be used in client components, or do you know of any way around it?

Comment: I think the toaster will only work in client components as it adds interactivity to the user and this is not possible to do in server components.

Comment: Is it because of the possibility of closing the toaster with a click event or is it because of the store you need to change the state across components? And do you know of any toaster implementation that works both in server and client components?

Comment: Its because it is impossible to run interactive code on server components. Server components get rendered on the server and only HTML and style gets sent to the client, so it cannot run any js on the client. In your case you are trying to display the 
client toast on the generation of the HTML on the server, which will not work. My opinion is the create a client component and send the data to it by props, then check it and display the toast.